# flip-coin scheme procedure

Tags: random, scheme, probability

I tried solving this problem
Flip-coin takes no arguements and returns the symbol heads or tails at random with equal probability.
This is what I got, but I do not understand why it is giving me the "impossible" can this be stopped?

```
(define flip-coin
    (lambda ( )
        (cond
            [ (= (random 2 ) 1 ) "heads" ]
            [ (= (random 2 ) 0 ) "tails" ]
            [else "impossible" ]
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `flip-coin` procedure returns only one of two possible values, it can be simplified a bit more, also noticing that `random` should be called only once - and there's no need to save its value in a variable, because the result is used immediately:

```
(define (flip-coin)
  (if (zero? (random 2))
      "tails"
      "heads"))
```

Answer (score 5):

You have two *different* calls to `random` in your `cond` statement. Both of these are independent and can give you different results. So it's possible that the first `(random 2)` evaluates to `0` and the second one evaluates to `1`, making both of those cases fail and giving you `"impossible"`.

The solution would be to put the result of `(random 2)` in a local variable with a let-statement, making sure to only call `random` *once*.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed that!